# Method of I18N for monotouch apps

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, xamarin.ios, app-store

Can I use public static classes with string constants for i18n my app? I mean, could Apple reject app, which is not use lproj-folders and strings-files for i18n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People are using all kind of solutions (including the use of .lproj, .net-like, gettext-like) and *I* never heard of a rejection based on this. I think the promotion of localized applications is much more important (to everyone, including Apple) that the tooling/tech choices to implement it.

OTOH rolling your own might not be the best way forward, i.e. problem other people solved are problems you wont have to solve yourself ;-)

Rdio has open sourced [vernacular](https://github.com/rdio/vernacular) which is targeted for mobile .NET applications (i.e. MonoTouch, Mono for Android and Windows phones).